# Como usar variable para operaciones matemáticas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una consulta en SQL Server, en la que estoy tratando de restar cantidades, sin embargo no he podido dar con la solución.

Este es el código de la consulta:

```
DECLARE @C_Ini numeric(10, 2) = (SELECT Cantidad FROM Kardex WHERE Id_Concepto = 1 AND 
CONVERT(DATE, FMovimiento) BETWEEN '01/01/2024' AND '17/01/2024' AND Clave_Material = 
'00005')
SELECT c.Cuenta,
   CONCAT(c.Cuenta, ' - ', c.SubCuenta, '  ', c.Descripcion_Corta) AS Movimiento,
   k.Folio,
   (CASE WHEN c.SubCuenta = 10 THEN k.Referencia_Compra ELSE k.Folio_Interno END) AS Referencia,
   k.FMovimiento AS Fecha,
   CASE WHEN c.Cuenta = 0 THEN k.Cantidad END AS C_Inicial,
   CASE WHEN c.Cuenta > 0 THEN k.Cantidad END AS MovimientoC,
   CASE WHEN c.Cuenta = 0 THEN @C_ini
        WHEN c.Cuenta = 1 THEN @C_ini + k.Cantidad
        WHEN c.Cuenta = 5 THEN @C_ini - k.Cantidad
   END
   AS ExistenciaF,
   e.Cantidad AS Existencia,
   CASE WHEN c.Cuenta IN (0, 1) THEN CONVERT(numeric(10, 3),(k.Cantidad * k.Costo)) ELSE 0 END AS Entrada,
   CASE WHEN c.Cuenta IN (5) THEN CONVERT(numeric(10, 3),(k.Cantidad * k.Costo)) ELSE 0 END AS Salida,
   k.Costo
FROM Kardex AS k
INNER JOIN Conceptos AS c ON c.Id_Concepto = k.Id_Concepto
INNER JOIN Existencias AS e ON e.Clave_Material = k.Clave_Material
WHERE k.Almacen = 2 AND k.Clave_Material = '00005' AND CONVERT(DATE, FMovimiento) 
BETWEEN '01/01/2024' AND '17/01/2024'
ORDER BY k.FMovimiento ASC
```

Y este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que en la variable se capture la cantidad inicial, para después en la consulta ir restando las demás cantidades, pero como se ve en la imagen no resulta del todo bien, ya que en todos los registros la variable se queda en 80 y resta las cantidades del renglón en cuestión, pero mi idea es como en los 2 primeros renglones, toma el valor 80 y le resta 10 del segundo renglón, y en ExistenciaF muestra 70, y después tomar el valor 70 y restarlo o sumarlo con la cantidad del tercer renglón, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: ¿`SUM` + multiplicar por -1 el valor dependiendo del caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no necesitas cambiar el valor de la variable. Como se mencionó en los comentarios, puedes sumar las filas de los movimientos para luego sumarlo a la cantidad inicial.

El único problema es que necesitas ir sumando las lineas, pero usualmente la función `SUM()` agrupa las filas. Afortunadamente, si usas la cláusula `OVER()` puedes hacer una suma progresiva. Encuentra más información de como usarla en [la documentación de Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Dejo un ejemplo simplificado de tus datos para que te des una idea de como hacerlo.

```
DECLARE @C_Ini numeric(10, 2) = 80;

SELECT Cuenta,
   CONCAT(Cuenta, ' - ', SubCuenta, '  ', Descripcion_Corta) AS Movimiento,
   Folio,
   Referencia,
   Fecha,
   CASE WHEN Cuenta = 0 THEN Cantidad END AS C_Inicial,
   CASE WHEN Cuenta > 0 THEN Cantidad END AS MovimientoC,
   @C_Ini + SUM(CASE WHEN Cuenta = 0 THEN 0
                     WHEN Cuenta = 1 THEN Cantidad
                     WHEN Cuenta = 5 THEN -Cantidad
                END) OVER( ORDER BY Fecha ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
   AS ExistenciaF,
   Cantidad AS Existencia,
   CASE WHEN Cuenta IN (0, 1) THEN CONVERT(numeric(10, 3),(Cantidad * Costo)) ELSE 0 END AS Entrada,
   CASE WHEN Cuenta IN (5) THEN CONVERT(numeric(10, 3),(Cantidad * Costo)) ELSE 0 END AS Salida,
   Costo
FROM (VALUES('0', '9' , 'Inv inic' , 90002,   0, CAST( '20240101' AS datetime), 20, 80, 15),
            ('5', '36', 'Ent a emp',  5081,  86, CAST( '20240102' AS datetime), 20, 10, 15),
            ('5', '36', 'Ent a emp',  5090,  94, CAST( '20240105' AS datetime), 20, 20, 15),
            ('5', '36', 'Ent a emp',  5102, 106, CAST( '20240108' AS datetime), 20, 10, 15),
            ('5', '36', 'Ent a emp',  5116, 118, CAST( '20240112' AS datetime), 20, 10, 15),
            ('5', '36', 'Ent a emp',  5128, 127, CAST( '20240116' AS datetime), 20, 10, 15)) t(Cuenta, SubCuenta, Descripcion_Corta, Folio, Referencia, Fecha, Existencia, Cantidad, Costo);
```